# Extract file name with a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a regular expressions to extract the filename of an url

```
https://example.net/img/src/img.jpg
```

I want to extract `img1.jpg`

I use urlparse from python but it extract the path in this way

```
img/src/img.jpg
```

How I can extract the file name with a regular expression

Comment: If you want regex, try `\/(\w+\.\w+$)`, but solution using `split()` IMHO is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a `split` on `/` and select the last element of the returned array (the best solution in my opinion)

or if you really want to use a regex you can use the following one

```
(?<=\/)(?:(?:\w+\.)*\w+)$
```

Note that only the following filenames are accepted: [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/WJE843/1)

You can adapt and change the `\w` to accept other characters if necessary.

**Explanations:**

- `(?<=\/)` positive lookbehind on `/` and `$` add the constraint that the filename string is the last element of the path
- `(?:(?:\w+\.)*\w+)` is used to extract words that are composed of several letters/digits and eventually underscores followed by a dot, this group can be repeated as many time as necessary (`xxx.tar.gz` file for example) and then followed by the final extension.

Answer (score 4):

Using `str.split` and negative indexing

```
url = "https://example.net/img/src/img.jpg"
print(url.split("/")[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
img.jpg
```

or using `os.path.basename`

```
import urlparse, os
url = "https://example.net/img/src/img.jpg"
a = urlparse.urlparse(url)
print(os.path.basename(a.path))   #--->img.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If your url pattern is static you can use positive lookahead ,

```
import re
pattern =r'\w+(?=\.jpg)'

text="""https://example.net/img/src/img.jpg
"""


print(re.findall(pattern,text)[0])
```

output:

```
img
```